# Password protected SwitchPreference

Tags: android, switchpreference

In my settings Fragment I have a password protected `SwitchPreference`. I use it to unlock an "Edit mode" in the app. Not everyone should be allowed into this mode so I've put a password on it. However, this causes a problem.

Initially clicking the `SwitchPreference` will switch it to the "ON" position, which will trigger my `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method. However, if the person gets the password wrong, it will then switch it to the "OFF" position, which will then trigger my `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method again!

So the problem is that I'm listening for when the `SwitchPreference` gets changed, but I should be listening for when it gets clicked. A quick search on StackOverflow or Google will tell you that you shouldn't be trying to listen for a click, and should listen for the `onSharedPreferenceChanged`. However, as I said, this doesn't suit my needs.

Does anyone know another method I can override here that will let me listen for when the `SwitchPreference` is clicked?

My goal is to listen for a click, if its switch is "ON", then just turn if "OFF". But if it's "OFF", then popup a password dialog. If the password is correct, set the switch to "ON", otherwise leave it "OFF".

Thanks

Comment: You could use (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#onClick%28%29)[this] maybe. But **beware** if you use click for `Switches` in Android, because you can switch these by dragging, and this won't trigger click events.

Comment: You could disable your preference per default and enable it via setEnabled(true) if the state is ON or the correct password is entered

Comment: That might be an option actually. Just use `setEnabled(false)` all the time and just listen for the `onClick` if possible. Although visually it might not be perfect.